# I need help looping data

Tags: r, for-loop

i have a folder with 800 r data files and within this file I have data about 800 participants so I had 2 conditions and the participants had to complete both these conditions soo 400 files about condition 1 and 400 files for condition 2.

The problem I'm having is with looping the participants data.

The for loop is below:

```
for (participant in 1:400) {
  for (drug_condition in c("d1", "d2")) {

 # Construct the file name for the current participant and trial
file_path <- file.path(data_directory, file_name)

load(file_path)

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you want to read and combine all the data files using loop?

Comment: yes, I want to read all the r files because within them there is values about age, condition, etc.

Comment: There are 2 issues. 1. The items to iterate are not mentioned anywhere in the loop (`participant` and `drug_condition`), and 2. you need to assign each element of the result of the loop into an object.

Comment: So would it be something like this? for (participant in 1:400) {
  for (drug_condition in c("d1", "d2")) {

    file_name <- paste0("Participant_", participant, "_", drug_condition, ".RData")
    file_path <- file.path(data_directory, file_name)

Comment: @Phil - `load()` should *immediately* restore objects to the environment so you shouldn't have to assign the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just use foreach() which will automatically store the results of each loop and combine them for you. The typical code is like:

```
#first get all the path into a list
data_directory<- list.files(#basic data files
  getwd(),# change path accordingly
  pattern = "*.csv", #define your file type
  full.names = TRUE
)

#loop read and combine
data_combined<-foreach(i = 1 :length(data_directory),.combine=rbind,.verbose = F)%do%{
    temp<-fread(data_directory[i],fill = T, check.names=T, header=T)
    }
```